# Logging the load balance

Tags: ruby, logging, server, ssh

I created a load balancing server at work and have to keep track of which server it adds the user to, so I wrote a little Ruby script that will do just that.

I'm looking for any critique of my work, can I do anything better at all.

Source(*user information, directory information, and server information changed for security*):

```
#!/local/usr/bin/ruby

require 'net/ssh'

@username = 'user'
@password =  nil
@host     = 'server_to_run_command_on'

def loadbalance_server_data(user)
  check = Net::SSH.start(@host, @username, :password => @password)
  cmd = "finduser #{user}" #<= Custom command that finds user info
  res = check.exec!(cmd)
  data = res
  write_data(data)
end

def write_data(data)
  File.open("path/to/log.txt", "a+"){ |s| s.puts(data) }
end

user_list = %w(user user user).each do |user|
  loadbalance_server_data(user)
end
```

Example of log:

> ```
> Querying: servers..
>
> Server usage report for user
>         server_name:  
>         server_name:  
>         server_name:  
>         server_name:  
>         server_name:  
>         server_name:  
>         server_name:  dbus-daemon gvfsd thunderbird #<= These programs always run on this server no matter what server they are logged in on
>         server_name:  
>         server_name:  
>         server_name:  dbus-daemon dbus-launch do_4000_clone_u execrulz gam_server gnome-screensav gnome-settings- gnome-vfs-daemo newphp openbox openbox-session qccm soffice soffice.bin tint2 umessage #<= The server the user is logged in on
>         server_name:
> ```

Comment: _I would also like to know if there is a way to have this program run at a certain time everyday?_  <- that is not on-topic here, the rest of the question is fine though.

Comment: See whats on topic here -> http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Caridorc Removed that chunk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Constants in UPPERCASE**

```
@username = 'user'
@password =  nil
@host     = 'server_to_run_command_on'
```

should be constants, as well as:

```
LOGFILE = "path/to/log.txt"
```

Marking a variable as constant in Ruby just needs upper-casing its name.

**Return value simplification**

```
res = check.exec!(cmd)
data = res
write_data(data)
```

Is unnecessarily long just write:

```
write_data( check.exec!(cmd) )
```

---

Other then this minor remarks, the code looks as straightforward and readable as it can get.

Comment: Why make them constants when I can just as easily make them instances? I understand the `LOGFILE` aspect of the constant, but not the `hostname; username; pass` part of it?

Comment: @Bam To me an instance outside of a class is confusing. Also a conatant will issue a warning if you try to modify it.

Comment: Or more clean:`write_data check.exec! cmd`